# Can't parse protobuf enum from int

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, protocol-buffers

I'm working on ASP.NET CORE 3.1 with protos3 and I need to parse an int to an enum on protouf.
When I use Enum.TryParse(int, out MyEnum myEnum), it succeeds even if the value doesn't exists.
For example:

Proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package MyProtos;

enum MyEnum { A = 0; B = 1; C = 2; }
```

I run the following code:

```
int x = 4;
if(Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(x, out var myEnum))
    Console.WriteLine($"MyEnum = {myEnum}")
x = 1
if(Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(x, out myEnum))
    Console.WriteLine($"MyEnum = {myEnum}")
```

The Output is:

```
MyEnum = 4
MyEnum = B
```

Expected Output is:

```
MyEnum = B
```

Comment: `Enum.TryParse<TEnum>` takes a `string`, not an `int`. Protobuf has no separate `Enum` class, nor are you even deserializing any Protobuf message, so it's not clear what you're doing here. Please provide a [mre]. Note that regardless of how the enum comes into being, `4` is an allowed value simply because .NET enums allow any value that fits the underlying integer type of the enum. `MyEnum e = (MyEnum) 4` is perfectly legal; use `Enum.IsDefined` if you want to check if there's a tag for the value.

Comment: thanks. Enum.IsDefined works as expected